# how to use httpx.AsyncClient as class member, and close asynchronously

Tags: python, python-3.x, aio, httpx

I want to use http client as a class member, but **del** function could not call await `client.aclose()`.
e.g.:

```
import httpx

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = httpx.AsyncClient()

    def __del__(self):
        await self.client.aclose()
```

refer: https://www.python-httpx.org/async/#opening-and-closing-clients
how to safely aclose?

Answer (score 3):

Although this is an older question, I may have something compelling to share as I had a similar situation. To @Isabi's point (Answered 2020-12-28), you need to use an event loop to decouple the client from your operations and then manually control it's lifecycle.

In my case, I need more control over the client such that I can separate the Request from the sending and when the client is closed so I can take advantage of session pooling, etc.  The example provided below shows how to use http.AsyncClient as a class member and close it on exit.

In figuring this out, I bumped into an Asyncio learning curve but quickly discovered that it's ... actually not too bad.  It's not as clean as Go[lang] but it starts making sense after an hour or two of fiddling around with it.  Full disclosure: I still question whether this is 100% correct.

The critical pieces are in the `__init__`, `close`, and the `__del__` methods.  What, to me, remains to be answered, is whether using a the http.AsyncClient in a context manager actually resets connections, etc.  I can only assume it does because that's what makes sense to me.  I can't help but wonder: is this even necessary?

```
import asyncio
import httpx
import time
from typing import Callable, List
from rich import print


class DadJokes:

    headers = dict(Accept='application/json')

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Since we want to reuse the client, we can't use a context manager that closes it.
        We need to use a loop to exert more control over when the client is closed.  
        """
        self.client = httpx.AsyncClient(headers=self.headers)
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    async def close(self):
        # httpx.AsyncClient.aclose must be awaited!
        await self.client.aclose()

    def __del__(self):
        """
        A destructor is provided to ensure that the client and the event loop are closed at exit.
        """
        # Use the loop to call async close, then stop/close loop.
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.close())
        self.loop.close()

    async def _get(self, url: str, idx: int = None):
        start = time.time() 
        response = await self.client.get(url)
        print(response.json(), int((time.time() - start) * 1000), idx)

    def get(self, url: str):
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self._get(url))

    def get_many(self, urls: List[str]):
        start = time.time()
        group = asyncio.gather(*(self._get(url, idx=idx) for idx, url in enumerate(urls)))
        self.loop.run_until_complete(group)
        print("Runtime: ", int((time.time() - start) * 1000))


url = 'https://www.icanhazdadjoke.com'
dj = DadJokes()
dj.get_many([url for x in range(4)])
```

Since I've been using Go as of late, I originally wrote some of these methods with closures as they seemed to make sense;  in the end I was able to (IMHO) provide a nice balance in between separation / encapsulation / isolation by converting the closures to class methods.

The resulting usage interface feels approachable and easy to read - I see myself writing class based async moving forward.

Comment: although the code you provided is workable, I still don't think it's a good practice to mix up sync & async code, as this gives much more complexity in terms of resource management.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be due to the fact that `client.aclose()` returns an `awaitable`, which cannot be awaited in a normal `def` function.

It could be worth giving a try with `asyncio.run(self.client.aclose())`. Here it might occur an exception, complaining that you are using a different `event loop` (or the same, I don't know much of your context so I can't tell) from currently running one. In this case you could get the currently running `event loop` and run the function from there.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html for more information on how you could accomplish it.

Comment: This doesn't work. Using `loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()` or `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()` both complain about nonexistent event loops. Running `asyncio.run(self.client.aclose())` gives an exception as you predicted.

Comment: It all depends on how you set it up. Probably the `event loop` is not running and that's why you cannot get it. Without much of a context it's difficoult to provide any hint. The best thing to do would be to open a new question..